# Indexer get and set different types

Tags: c#

I have problem with indexer in C#. As requirement I must implement indexer. This indexer must accept as value (set) generic type `<T>` and return (get) type `MyClass<T>`.

Example:

```
class OtherClass<T>{
   Dictionary<string, MyClass<T>> dict; 
   //...
}    

class MyClass<T>{
   T item;
   //...
   public void MethodFromMyClass(){
      //...
   }
}

MyClass<String> mc = new MyClass<String>();      
mc["Name"] = "Data";

//Call method from MyClass
mc["Name"].MethodFromMyClass()
```

I tried a lot of things for example. `public object this[string i] ...`, but none of them produce the expected results. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you should show more of your code. You are creating an instance of `MyClass`, called `mc`, and you treat it as a `Dictionary` (with `mc["Name"]` ...).

Comment: What is `OtherClass<T>` here? Did you mean for `mc` to actually be an instance of `OtherClass<T>`? Also, what does it mean _semantically_ to assign a `string` value to an indexer that returns an instance of `MyClass<T>`? You should show the actual indexer code that you would like to be able to write. You can't do exactly what you want, since a class can contain only one indexer for any given parameter type, but maybe if you explain what you're actually trying to do, an appropriate answer can be given.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to make an indexer whose getter is a different type than its setter? That's a horrible idea, and C# was specifically designed to make it hard to do things that are horrible ideas (they prefer to lead you to the "pit of success"). Whatever you're doing, it's not something that you can meaningfully model with an indexer. Use two methods instead, one to set a value of type `T`, one to get the `MyClass<T>` wrapper. Your users will thank you.

Comment: @JoeWhite I agree with you, but this my project on university and I have this indexer in specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implict operator can help you. First, we should define implict operator for `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private readonly T item;

    public MyClass(T item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void PrintItem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }

    public static implicit operator MyClass<T>(T d)
    {
        return new MyClass<T>(d);
    }
}
```

Next, we should define `DictionaryClass` with `MyClass` indexer:

```
public class DictionaryClass<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, MyClass<T>> dict;

    public DictionaryClass()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass<T>>();
    }

    public MyClass<T> this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            return dict[index];
        }
        set
        {
            dict[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public void Run()
{
    var myDictionary = new DictionaryClass<string>();
    myDictionary["Name"] = "Data";
    myDictionary["Name"].PrintItem(); // Prints "Data"
}
```